# Migration of existing WLI,ESB,BPM and Portal in to Spring Micro services

Tags: esb, jbpm, portal, business-process-management, wli

I want to convert our existing application containing `UI`,`WLI`,`BPM` and `ESB` with Spring Micro services.

Please give me suggestion how we will migrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is answer a couple of questions:
 - Why migrate?
 - What current problems do I solve with migration? which not?
 - Why a microservices architecture?

You do not specify it, but because of the technologies you name, it seems that you already have an SOA architecture. Do not forget that microservices can be seen as a subset of SOA

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25625813/4727991

Now yes, taking into account the above we can go to the concrete. Since changing architecture to a solution can be very costly, consider a gradual approach:

- Detects applications (probably monolithic) that do many things and share them in multiple independent services. The objective of this is to improve the response times to improvements and corrections, minimizing the impact on other services. In addition to being able to scale separately.
      The ideal is to isolate them completely. But you have to have criteria when dividing your monoliths, or you could get the opposite effect over time.
- You have to think how to route and balance your services. Your ESB may be too big for this or even more expensive to configure than a product designed for this as Zuul (https://github.com/Netflix/zuul). Which also integrates very well with Spring Boot (https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/)
- You still have the BPM (apparently JBPM), which could be too expensive to migrate depending on the size and type of processes.
      You could migrate the smaller processes, with less human interaction (HTs) and the automatic ones.
- You could take your user interfaces (including the processes) to independent SPA apps that authenticate against your own Authorization Server (OAuth2). It could be behind zuul too. In this way it would be relatively easy to go towards an SSO

This is just the tip of the iceberg, depending on your context and requirements can be transformed and evolve in different ways

I hope it helps you